# Can an existing Kubernetes cluster be converted to openshift cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I have a kubernetes cluster with 1 master node and 4 worker nodes?

Is it possible to convert this cluster to openshift?

Comment: No, you should install new OpenShift cluster separately, and you should migrate your pod to the new OpenShift cluster from your Kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess no. You may plan to gradually move your workloads to a new Openshift cluster.
There's also a [migration tool](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.4/migration/migrating_3_4/about-migration.html) which is not supporting migration from kubernetes clusters at the moment, but might in the future.